# Mutate logic for lists

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to add elements to a list using existing slots of this very list. In base `R` I would use the following syntax:

```r
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2, e = 1, f = 1)
## Add slot c and d  which take the values from a and b respectively
l$c <- l$a
l$d <- l$b
str(l)
# List of 6
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ b: num 2
#  $ e: num 1
#  $ f: num 1
#  $ c: num 1
#  $ d: num 2
```

Avoiding `l$` can be done via `attach` / `with` / `within` which I do not want to use.

So what is the canonical way of doing that with `tidyverse`? One solution I could think of is:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2, e = 1, f = 1)
str(l %$% list_modify(l, c = a, d = b))
str(l)
# List of 6
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ b: num 2
#  $ e: num 1
#  $ f: num 1
#  $ c: num 1
#  $ d: num 2
```

But as there are plenty of functions in the `tidyverse` I was wondering whether there is afunction which is "more" fit for purpose, i.e. using maybe less different libraries / function calls?

---

*Update.* Adapted the example slightly to highlight that not all columns will be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Not a tidy way but you can do :

```
append_list <- function(l, copy_from, copy_to) {
  if(length(copy_from) != length(copy_to)) 
    stop('length of copy_from and copy_to should be equal')
  l[copy_to] <- l[copy_from]
  l
}

append_list(l, c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'd'))

#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 2

#$e
#[1] 1

#$f
#[1] 1

#$c
#[1] 1

#$d
#[1] 2
```

```
append_list(l, c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'd', 'e'))
```

> Error in append_list(l, c("a", "b"), c("c", "d", "e")) :
> length of copy_from and copy_to should be equal

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
c(l, setNames(l, c("c", "d")))
```

**edit**

Without checking if elements exist in list or if name is already taken (although list can have same names):

```
copy_ele <- c("a", "b")
new_names <- c("c", "d")
c(l, setNames(l[copy_ele], new_names))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this becomes even worse in maintenance if I do not want to copy all slots. I see that my example was oversimplified, I will adapt. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited answer to reflect your changes.